# TFS 2010 Beta 1 Creating Team Projects programmatically

Tags: tfs

is it possible to use some API call to create a new team project (i.e. add a new team project to the Project Collection on TFS 2010)?  If yes, what is it? I was searching high and low for this...

So far I found how to script it and then call an executable from the command line: http://blogs.msdn.com/granth/archive/2009/09/25/scripting-team-project-creation-in-tfs2010.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work with Beta 1, but it will work with Beta 2 - which will be out very soon. You'll want to take a reference on Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.dll (under \Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies). Then you can new up a BatchTeamProjectCreator object and call its BatchCreateTeamProject method. You'll need to pass in a settings file in the same format Grant described in his blog post.